# Yii2 - yii\grid\CheckboxColumn - Bulk insert selected rows into another table

Tags: yii2

Let's say I have two tables containing almost similar fields:

> Table A: id, name, address, class_id
>
> Table B: id, name, class_id

Using yii\grid\CheckboxColumn, I can select some rows in Table A.

My question is:
After selecting particular rows using checkboxes from Table A, how can we insert them to the Table B?

Answer (score 0):

According [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html) you can get array of selected row keys with JS

```
var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

You can use ajax to send it to corresponding controller/action where you have to load values from A and save it to B. 
Or just use the keys as value of hidden input and post it to controller.